# Geofencing Intent Not Firing

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, geofencing

Hello everyone i am implementing geofencing feature in my android application to send toast notifications.The thing is when i am inside(where i am making fences) a fence that i have created then the intent is fired but when i try to fire the event again by reentering the location intent is not firing here is my code

```
    protected override void OnHandleIntent (Intent intent)
    {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();


        var geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.FromIntent (intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.HasError) {
            var errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.GetErrorString (this, geofencingEvent.ErrorCode);
            Log.Error (TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.GeofenceTransition;

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GeofenceTransitionEnter ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GeofenceTransitionExit) {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Service Started", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            IList<IGeofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.TriggeringGeofences;

            string geofenceTransitionDetails = GetGeofenceTransitionDetails (this, geofenceTransition, triggeringGeofences);

            SendNotification (geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.Info (TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.Error (TAG, GetString (Resource.String.geofence_transition_invalid_type, new [] { new Java.Lang.Integer (geofenceTransition) }));
        }
    }

    string GetGeofenceTransitionDetails (Context context, int geofenceTransition, IList<IGeofence> triggeringGeofences)
    {
        string geofenceTransitionString = GetTransitionString (geofenceTransition);

        var triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new List<string> ();
        foreach (IGeofence geofence in triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.Add (geofence.RequestId);
        }
        var triggeringGeofencesIdsString = string.Join (", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    void SendNotification (string notificationDetails)
    {
        var notificationIntent = new Intent (ApplicationContext, typeof(MainActivity));

        var stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create (this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack (Java.Lang.Class.FromType (typeof(MainActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent (notificationIntent);

        var notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent (0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (this);
        builder.SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.icon)
            .SetLargeIcon (BitmapFactory.DecodeResource (Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
            .SetColor (Color.Red)
            .SetContentTitle (notificationDetails)
            .SetContentText (GetString (Resource.String.geofence_transition_notification_text))
            .SetContentIntent (notificationPendingIntent);

        builder.SetAutoCancel (true);

        var mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService (Context.NotificationService);
        mNotificationManager.Notify (0, builder.Build ());
    }

    string GetTransitionString (int transitionType)
    {
        switch (transitionType) {
        case Geofence.GeofenceTransitionEnter:
            return GetString (Resource.String.geofence_transition_entered);
        case Geofence.GeofenceTransitionExit:
            return GetString (Resource.String.geofence_transition_exited);
        default:
            return GetString (Resource.String.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }
    }
```

and my main activity is

```
{
    protected const string TAG = "creating-and-monitoring-geofences";
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected IList<IGeofence> mGeofenceList;
    bool mGeofencesAdded;
    PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
    ISharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    Button mAddGeofencesButton;
    Button mRemoveGeofencesButton;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.main_activity);

        mAddGeofencesButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.add_geofences_button);
        mRemoveGeofencesButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.remove_geofences_button);

        mAddGeofencesButton.Click += AddGeofencesButtonHandler;
        mRemoveGeofencesButton.Click += RemoveGeofencesButtonHandler;
        mGeofenceList = new List<IGeofence> ();
        mGeofencePendingIntent = null;

        mSharedPreferences = GetSharedPreferences (Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME,
            FileCreationMode.Private);

        mGeofencesAdded = mSharedPreferences.GetBoolean (Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, false);

        SetButtonsEnabledState ();
        PopulateGeofenceList ();
        BuildGoogleApiClient ();
    }

    protected void BuildGoogleApiClient ()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder (this)
            .AddConnectionCallbacks (this)
            .AddOnConnectionFailedListener (this)
            .AddApi (LocationServices.API)
            .Build ();
    }
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.Connect ();


    }
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.Connect();
    }

    protected override void OnStop ()
    {
      base.OnStop ();
    //    mGoogleApiClient.Disconnect ();
    }

    public void OnConnected (Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        Log.Info (TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
    }

    public void OnConnectionSuspended (int cause)
    {
        Log.Info (TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    public void OnConnectionFailed (Android.Gms.Common.ConnectionResult result)
    {
        Log.Info (TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.ErrorCode);
    }

    GeofencingRequest GetGeofencingRequest ()
    {
        var builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder ();
        builder.SetInitialTrigger (GeofencingRequest.InitialTriggerEnter);
        builder.AddGeofences (mGeofenceList);

        return builder.Build ();
    }

    public async void AddGeofencesButtonHandler (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.IsConnected) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, GetString (Resource.String.not_connected), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            return;
        }

        try {
            var status = await LocationServices.GeofencingApi.AddGeofencesAsync (mGoogleApiClient, GetGeofencingRequest (),
                GetGeofencePendingIntent ());
            HandleResult (status);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            LogSecurityException(securityException);
        }
    }

    public async void RemoveGeofencesButtonHandler (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.IsConnected) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, GetString(Resource.String.not_connected), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            return;
        }
        try {
            var status = await LocationServices.GeofencingApi.RemoveGeofencesAsync (mGoogleApiClient, 
                GetGeofencePendingIntent ());
            HandleResult (status);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            LogSecurityException (securityException);
        }
    }

    void LogSecurityException (SecurityException securityException)
    {
        Log.Error (TAG, "Invalid location permission. " +
            "You need to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with geofences", securityException);
    }

    public void HandleResult (Statuses status)
    {
        if (status.IsSuccess) {
            mGeofencesAdded = !mGeofencesAdded;
            var editor = mSharedPreferences.Edit ();
            editor.PutBoolean (Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, mGeofencesAdded);
            editor.Commit ();

            SetButtonsEnabledState ();

            Toast.MakeText (
                this,
                GetString (mGeofencesAdded ? Resource.String.geofences_added :
                    Resource.String.geofences_removed),
                ToastLength.Short
            ).Show ();
        } else {
            var errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.GetErrorString (this,
                status.StatusCode);
            Log.Error (TAG, errorMessage);
        }
    }

    PendingIntent GetGeofencePendingIntent ()
    {
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        }
        //var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Test));
        //SendBroadcast(intent);
        //return PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService));
        //SendBroadcast(intent);
        return PendingIntent.GetService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    }

    public void PopulateGeofenceList ()
    {
        foreach (var entry in Constants.BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS) {
            mGeofenceList.Add (new GeofenceBuilder ()
                .SetRequestId (entry.Key)
                .SetCircularRegion (
                    entry.Value.Latitude,
                    entry.Value.Longitude,
                    Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                )
                .SetExpirationDuration (Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .SetTransitionTypes (Geofence.GeofenceTransitionEnter |
                    Geofence.GeofenceTransitionExit)
                .Build ());
        }
    }

    void SetButtonsEnabledState ()
    {
        if (mGeofencesAdded) {
            mAddGeofencesButton.Enabled = false;
            mRemoveGeofencesButton.Enabled = true;
        } else {
            mAddGeofencesButton.Enabled = true;
            mRemoveGeofencesButton.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

also i have tried making a broadcast reciever but it didnt helped me much

Comment: How are you testing your GeoFence. If you are using Google's API, I had to move my current location via a mock-location provider in and out of the fence in a realistic manner for it to fire, so jumping from 100km away and a second later inside the fence wouldn't fire. If I moved at a walking or driving speed from outside to in (and let it sit inside for a few calls) then it would fire.

Comment: @MorrisonChang actually i did created a fence 100 meters away from my current location and i walked towards the fence in 3 minutes is that not enough? or should it be more?

Comment: @MorrisonChang is there any reliable api for geofencing? instead of google api which works fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your code looks exactly like the sample you pull from the google developer page, and is the one many people is using more commonly at first. I myself was having issues with accuracy and missing fence transitions with that one too. I read that manually adding an instance of the previous location request package (LocationManager) and explicitly specifying GPS as a provider in high update mode can make it more accurate. That's how I have it working now. You can also try making your fences' radii wider, that way you will take into account the minimum wi-fi accuracy which is stated to be around 50m not considering drift.

Comment: i used broadcast reciever instead of intent service and my results got better also the radius i set it was minimum 100 meters so that also helped btw i posted it a long way back thanks for answering